# How to list data in the attribute table in the same order as I selected the data?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a map that consists of a number of pipes that are connected to each other. Is there a way I can list data in the attribute table in the same order as I selected the data?

For example: I select first pipe1, then pipe5, then pipe7 and then in the attribute table the first item on the list is pipe1, second pipe5 and third pipe7.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tool *per se*, but what I have done in the past is to add a field called "List ID" then number the records in the order I want to see them and then perform a sort. For small groups it is fine; I can imagine for large groups this would be rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the **Move selection to top** option in your *Attribute Table* to achieve this. Note that your selected features will always be listed in ascending order by their **feature row number** (shown in the red box):

[image: Move selection option]

Comment: Yes that is true, but the order of the list is still governed by some other rule. In your screenshot the selected data order is put as ascending order. But I would like to have my data to be in the same exact order as I selected it.

Comment: @kristallograafia - That would be a nice feature to have :). Not sure if it's possible at the moment.